# How to get an input value on a Visualforce page from an Apex controller?

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, force.com

Let's pretend that I have an *sObject* called *MyCutomObject* with the fields *Column1*, *Column2*, *Column3*, *PickMeColumn* and others. The type of the *PickMeColumn* is *Picklist*.

While it's easy to access the object's instance data in my page, I'm a bit stucked with how to get the user's input data from that page to be accessible inside the controller.

Page code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="MyCustomObject__c" extensions="MyCustomSearchController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Criteria">
            <apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:inputField value="{!myObject.PickMeColumn__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:commandButton value="Search" id="SearchButton" action="{!search}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock title="Search Results">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myObjectList}" var="myObject">
                <apex:repeat value="{!myObject}" var="aRecord">
                    <apex:column value="{!aRecord.Column1__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!aRecord.Column2__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!aRecord.Column3__c}"/>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller code:

```
public class MyCustomSearchController {
    public MyCutomObject__c myObject {get;set;}
    public List<MyCutomObject__c> myObjectList {get;set;}

    public MyCustomSearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    }

    public PageReference search() {
        String ValueSelectedByUser = '??? Help!';
        myObjectList = [SELECT Column1__c, Column2__c, Column3__c FROM MyCutomObject__c WHERE PickMeColumn__c = ValueSelectedByUser];
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }
}
```

Comment: @jordan.baucke It's actually http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: whoops that's my mistake!

Answer (score 0):

In controller's code simply like so:

```
public class MyCustomSearchController {
    public MyCutomObject__c myObject {get;set;}
    public List<MyCutomObject__c> myObjectList {get;set;}

    public MyCustomSearchController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        myObject = new myCustomObject__c(); // Must create the object!
    }

    public PageReference search() {
        String ValueSelectedByUser = myObject.PickMeColumn__c;
        myObjectList = [SELECT Column1__c, Column2__c, Column3__c FROM MyCutomObject__c WHERE PickMeColumn__c = :ValueSelectedByUser];
        // Have to add the colon
        return ApexPages.currentPage();
    }
}
```